# Do external style sheets need to have .css ending?

Tags: css

I'd like to dynamically create my style sheet in PHP. So (without using .htaccess to tell the server to parse .css as PHP) my style sheet would end in `.php`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.php">
```

Does that work? Is it within specification?

Comment: This not an actual answer but have ever tried LESS? It can be used perhaps for in your case?

Comment: LESS is interesting, but I don't want my styles to depend on JS being activated in the client's browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `text/css` mime type to the output of that php file, so the browser can understand better. The extension is not a requirement.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
?>
```

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?21617-Dynamic-external-js-scripts-and-css-stylesheets-with-PHP